# Using VARCHAR as a foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation

I've got 4 tables which has one relation between them. Mother and Child-tables are working with VARCHAR as a primary key and as a foreign key in child table. But I can't figure it out why retailer - ram is giving me error?

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`retailer` (
  `retailer_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `retailer_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`retailer_number`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`rma` (
  `rma_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `retailer_retailer_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rma_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rma_retailer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`retailer_retailer_number`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`retailer` (`retailer_number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
CREATE INDEX `fk_rma_retailer1_idx` ON `mydb`.`rma` (`retailer_retailer_number` ASC);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- This is working
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`mother` (
  `motherName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `test` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`motherName`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`child`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`child` (
  `idchild` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `childName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `mother_motherName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idchild`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_child_mother`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mother_motherName`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`mother` (`motherName`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_child_mother_idx` ON `mydb`.`child` (`mother_motherName` ASC);
```

**ERROR**

150422 13:10:28 Error in foreign key constraint of table mydb/rma:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`retailer_retailer_number`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`retailer` (`retailer_number`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.

**Question**

If the reason is that collation, how can I change it in MySQLWorkbench at once or where is coming from?

Comment: Does the retailer table have an index on the retailer_number field?

Comment: "Cannot find an index..." -- Please perform `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.

Comment: The problem was in this line: COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci; Schema collate was utf8-default collation BUT in error tables there was their own table schema and even own collation in couple of variables. I changed that and everything is working fine. In MysqlWorkbench Table schema is hidden by default.